# iOS Bluetooth Programming - Trouble establishing p2p between two iPad's

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, p2p

Im sorta new to bluetooth programming on the iPhone and i wanted to set up a PeerToPeer bluetooth connectivity between two iOS devices. I followed the steps in this tutorial

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1

and everything happens as it should until i get the accept or decline option when another device has been detected.

As soon as i choose accept, the app crashes on BOTH devices. And the error message shown is this:-

wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
2012-03-05 15:40:25.809 Bluetooth[204:707] -[ViewController session:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x367fe0
2012-03-05 15:40:25.811 Bluetooth[204:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController session:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x367fe0'

Anybody know whats going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some of your code. Are you implementing didFailWithError? Why are you following that tutorial rather than reading the documentation and examples Apple provide?

Comment: have you implement GKsessionDelegate method - (void)session:(GKSession *)session didFailWithError:(NSError *)error; in your class?

Comment: From comments: In case people weren't able to build and run successfully, you need to import the GameKit framework (rightclick frameworks folder > existing frameworks >GameKit.framework) and replace the empty #import statement in .h with #import . Delete the empty #import in .m.

Comment: Also, you guys were right, i had not implemented the didFailWithError, which meant that the error was of thrown by the [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil] and i did not provide a provision at first, to log the error or handle it by writing the didFailWithError.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy pasting this from coments below in the link you posted:

In case people weren't able to build and run successfully, you need to import the `GameKit framework` (rightclick frameworks folder > existing frameworks > GameKit.framework)

Add, to the **BluetoothViewController.h** file:

```
#import "GameKit/GKSession.h"
#import "GameKit/GKPeerPickerController.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem. Made a rather silly mistake!

Ive written a method as follows

```
- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker 
              didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID 
                   toSession:(GKSession *) session {
```

and in it i set up the app to receive data via bluetooth using

```
[session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
```

I thought i would check if the connection is established first and then think about the data transfer. But turns out you can't do that coz the data handler has been set and i had not implemented it in self. When i did write that though, it worked fine!

Hope, this stope people from committing such obvious mistakes!